# Making a Unix-specific CMake procedure cross-platform

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform, portability, cmake-modules

I've written a small CMake module for, well, it doesn't matter what for. The point is that it acts as follows:

- When the appropriate CMake function is invoked, a shell script with relative path `scripts/whatever.sh` (under the project directory) is invoked.
- The shell script `cat`'s a 'here-file' containing a C program to the C compiler found by CMake (with fallback to `cc`)
- The program is compiled, linked and run, producing some text
- The output text is saved as a CMake variable

This is relatively robust on Unix-like systems, where `cat` and `bash` are available and when the path separator is `/`. (There may be other assumptions I'm ignoring.) But - I want this to work on Windows, and other systems as well. How do I go about doing this?

Notes:

- In case it's relevant: The [shell script](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/scripts/get_cuda_sm.sh) and the [CMake module](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/cmake/Modules/HandleCUDAComputeCapability.cmake).
- I can use C++ instead of C if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may use CMake scripts for being cross-platform. Many things may be performed directly in `CMakeLists.txt` and scripts included from it:

- "Here in document" support in CMake is not the best, but it is not very difficult to store text of a small program into a CMake variable.
- `execute_process` is able to run external programs from CMake script and store output of that program in CMake variable. Also, `try_compile` or `try_run` may be useful in some scenarios.